# Time Complexity for LeetCode 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

> Problem: Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring
> without repeating characters.
>
> Example: Input: s = "abcabcbb" Output: 3 Explanation: The answer is
> "abc", with the length of 3.

My solution:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        seen = set()
        l = r = curr_len = max_len = 0
        n = len(s)
        
        while l < n:
            if r < n and s[r] not in seen:
                seen.add(s[r])
                curr_len += 1
                max_len = max(curr_len, max_len)
                r += 1
            else:
                l += 1
                r = l
                curr_len = 0
                seen.clear()
                
        return max_len
```

I know this is not an efficient solution, but I am having trouble figuring out its time complexity.

I visit every character in the string but, for each one of them, the window expands until it finds a repeated char. So every char ends up being visited multiple times, but not sure if enough times to justify an O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity and, obviously, it's way worse than O(n).

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests regarding software theory or advice.

Comment: This is not open-ended. It is a specific problem that has a specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could claim the algorithm to be O(n) if you know the size of the character set your input can be composed of, because the length your window can expand is limited by the number of different characters you could pass over before encountering a duplicate, and this is capped by the size of the character set you're working with, which itself is some constant independent of the length of the string. For example, if you are only working with lower case alphabetic characters, the algorithm is O(26n) = O(n).

To be more exact you could say that it runs in O(n*(min(m,n)) where n is the length of the string and m is the number of characters in the alphabet of the string. The reason for the min is that even if you're somehow working with an alphabet of unlimited unique characters, at worst you're doing a double for loop to the end of the string. That means however that if the number of possible characters you can encounter in the string exceeds the string's length you have a worst case O(n^2) performance (which occurs when every character of the string is unique).

Comment: That is very true! For large n, every iteration would be capped at 26 until I reach iteration n-26 and forward, for which it will be capped at less than 26 cause it would would reach the end of the string before 26 anyway. But yes, for large n it would be O(26n). **Follow-up**: what if I provide an early termination condition stating that if at any given iteration I reach the end of the string, the algorithm is done because that would be the maximum length. What would be the time complexity?

Comment: **Answer**: I believe it would still be O(26n) for large n, because the early termination would only be useful when I enter iteration n-26 and forward. The only time it would be O(n^2) is if all characters of the string are unique, which for large n it doesn't happen unless I am somehow working with a magical infinite alphabet

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of Chinese or Unicode charsets with 10s of thousands of characters in which the worst case n^2 behavior is much more practically realizable, but you're right, magical alphabet case aside m is still at most some large constant and it's asymptotically O(n).

Comment: And I agree that that kind of early termination check probably doesn't change things, for the reason you said for smaller alphabets and because for n < m cases it just turns the worst case into something like a palindrome with complexity like (n-1) + (n-3) + (n-5)... ~= (n^2)/4.

Comment: Since when assessing the complexity of an algorithm you drop all constants O(26n) = O(n)